# Android allow multiple file upload (Max 150 MB) to PHP Server

Tags: php, android, file-upload, httpurlconnection

I have to allow a user to upload multiple files(can be image/video/audio)in a single request from my android application to the PHP server. I am using REST web service.

For this functionality, I am using the following code:

```
/* To upload the multiple documents */
public void uploadFile() {
    String charset = "UTF-8";
    File[] uploadFileArray = new File[mediaList.size()];

    for (int i = 0; i < mediaList.size(); i++) {
        uploadFileArray[i] = new File(mediaList.get(i).getMediaPath());
    }

    try {
        MultipartUtility multipart = new MultipartUtility(upLoadServerUri, charset);

        for (int i = 0; i < mediaList.size(); i++) {
            if (isImage)) {
                multipart.addFilePart("image_doc[]", uploadFileArray[i]);
            } 
            else if (isVideo) {
                multipart.addFilePart("video_doc[]", uploadFileArray[i]);
            } 
            else if (isAudio) {
                multipart.addFilePart("audio_doc[]", uploadFileArray[i]);
            }
        }

        List<String> responseUploadDocument = multipart.finish();
        System.out.println("SERVER REPLIED:");

        for (String line : responseUploadDocument) {
            System.out.println(line);
            responseUploadDocumentString = line;
        }

        if (responseUploadDocumentString != null) {
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(responseUploadDocumentString);
            statusUploadDoc = jsonObj.getString("status");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And my MultipartUtility Class is as follows:

```
public class MultipartUtility {
    private final String boundary;
    private static final String LINE_FEED = "\r\n";
    private HttpURLConnection httpConn;
    private String charset;
    private OutputStream outputStream;
    private PrintWriter writer;

    public MultipartUtility(String requestURL, String charset)
            throws IOException {
        this.charset = charset;

        boundary = "===" + System.currentTimeMillis() + "===";

        URL url = new URL(requestURL);
        httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        ***httpConn.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);***
        httpConn.setUseCaches(false);
        httpConn.setDoOutput(true); // indicates POST method
        httpConn.setDoInput(true);

        httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
        httpConn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "CodeJava Agent");
        httpConn.setRequestProperty("Test", "Bonjour");

        outputStream = httpConn.getOutputStream();
        writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, charset),
                true);
    }

    public void addFormField(String name, String value) {
        writer.append("--" + boundary).append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + name + "\"")
                .append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.append("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=" + charset).append(
                LINE_FEED);
        writer.append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.append(value).append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.flush();
    }

    public void addFilePart(String fieldName, File uploadFile)
            throws IOException {
        String fileName = uploadFile.getName();
        writer.append("--" + boundary).append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.append(
                "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + fieldName
                        + "\"; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"")
                .append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.append(
                "Content-Type: "
                        + URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(fileName))
                .append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.append("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary").append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.flush();

        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(uploadFile);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead = -1;
        while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        outputStream.flush();
        inputStream.close();

        writer.append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.flush();
    }

    public void addHeaderField(String name, String value) {
        writer.append(name + ": " + value).append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.flush();
    }

    public List<String> finish() throws IOException {
        List<String> response = new ArrayList<String>();

        writer.append(LINE_FEED).flush();
        writer.append("--" + boundary + "--").append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.close();

        // checks server's status code first
        int status = httpConn.getResponseCode();
        if (status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    httpConn.getInputStream()));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                response.add(line);
            }
            reader.close();
            httpConn.disconnect();
        } else {
            throw new IOException("Server returned non-OK status: " + status);
        }

        return response;
    }
}
```

But now the problem is:

On Local Server:

- Allow to upload till 16MB [if setChunkedStremmingMode(0) is not set]
- Allow to upload till 150MB [if setChunkedStremmingMode(0) is set]

On Live Server:

- Allow to upload till 16MB [if setChunkedStremmingMode(0) is not set]
- Disallow to upload a single KB file [if setChunkedStremmingMode(0) is set]

My both local and live servers have the same configurations. I don't understand why setChunkedStremmingMode(0) doesn't work for the live server.

Comment: plz give your input if issue is resolved, if not do give feedback what is problem.

Comment: did you get "Android:java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 23970828-byte allocation with 2097152 free bytes and 2MB until OOM" this error while uploading files from an android device? I am getting this error and I have also added allow a heap size to true but still, it will crash because I have uploaded the big size of images. can someone help me what should I do?

Answer (score 4):

I have a project which can upload image/file size of **up to 48-50 MB**. [I'm using Retrofit for Network communication.]
Here is the link to the Sample Project: https://github.com/DearDhruv/Retrofit-with-EventBus

Here is code:

```
private void startUploading(final File file) {

    if (file == null || !isPictureValid(file.getAbsolutePath())) {
        showMsg("File is not valid, try again.");
    } else if (file.exists()) {
        showProgressDialog();
        String mimeType = "image/jpeg"
                // "application/octet-stream"
                // "multipart/form-data"
                // "image/*"
                // "multipart/mixed"
                ;

        TypedFile typedFile = new TypedFile(mimeType, file);
        mApiClient.uploadFile(UPLOAD_FILE_REQUEST_TAG, typedFile);

    } else {
        showMsg("File is corrupted.");
    }
}
```

Here is server-side code:

```
class ImageUploadStatus {
    public $result_code = 0;
    public $message = "Image upload failed.";}
    class ImageResults {
    public $name = "";
    public $url = "";
    public $size = "";
}
$status = new ImageUploadStatus ();
$results = new ImageResults ();

if ($_FILES ["file"] ["error"] > 0) {
    header ( "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request" );
    // echo "Error: " . $_FILES ["file"] ["error"] . "<br /> \n";
    $status->message = "Error: " . $_FILES ["file"] ["error"];
} else {
    if ($_FILES ["file"] ["error"] > 0) {
        // echo "Error: " . $_FILES ["file"] ["error"] . "<br /> \n";
        $status->message = "Error: " . $_FILES ["file"] ["error"];
    } else {
        // echo "Upload: " . $_FILES ["file"] ["name"] . "<br /> \n";
        // echo "Type: " . $_FILES ["file"] ["type"] . "<br /> \n";
        // echo "Size: " . ($_FILES ["file"] ["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br /> \n";
        // echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES ["file"] ["tmp_name"] . "<br /> \n";
    }

    $target_path = "../api/uploads/";
    $target_path = $target_path . basename ( $_FILES ['file'] ['name'] );

    //if (is_uploaded_file ( $_FILES ['uploadedfile'] ['tmp_name'] )) {
        // echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
        //$status->message = "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
    //}

    if (move_uploaded_file ( $_FILES ['file'] ['tmp_name'], $target_path )) {
        // echo "The file " . basename ( $_FILES ['file'] ['name'] ) . " has been uploaded";

        $status->message = "Image upload successful";
        $status->result_code = 1;

        $results->name = $_FILES ["file"] ["name"] . "";
        $results->url = $target_path . "";
        $results->size = ($_FILES ["file"] ["size"] / 1); // 1024 to convert in KB
    } else {
        // echo "There was an error Moving the file, please try again!";
        //$status->message = "There was an error Moving the file, please try again!";

         switch($_FILES['file']['error']){
            case 0: //no error; possible file attack!
              $status->message =  "There was a problem with your upload.";
              break;
            case 1: //uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini
              $status->message =  "The file you are trying to upload is too big.";
              break;
            case 2: //uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the html form
              $status->message =  "The file you are trying to upload is too big.";
              break;
            case 3: //uploaded file was only partially uploaded
                $status->message =  "The file you are trying upload was only partially uploaded.";
              break;
            case 4: //no file was uploaded
              $status->message =  "You must select an image for upload.";
              break;
            default: //a default error, just in case!  :)
              $status->message =  "There was a problem with your upload.";
              break;
          }

        }

    $response = array (
            'status' => $status,
            'results' => $results 
    );

    // echo (json_encode ( $status ));
    // echo (json_encode ( $results ));
    echo (json_encode ( $response ));
}
```

I guess this might be helpful.

You might also need to give the max size of upload file in PHP configuration.

Comment: All the work you put into this is great. Just please remember links can die and your answer be rendered useless. Also you are forcing the OPs to go through a lot of code when it may not solve their issue. Add inside your post useful highlights of what you did different than the OP and why your code works while his doesn't.

Comment: You change your github username and your github links die, unfortunately. The edit is great.

Answer (score 1):

Please check these two settings in php.ini file on your server which handles file upload.

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 150M

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 150M
```

You need to make these settings proper first on your server then only big file upload will work properly.
Also check the settings on your local server. These settings are more important before writing the code to handle upload because your code is correct according to me as file upload is working for you. The problem seems to be with php.ini settings....

Comment: Please share what setting you have on your server and local??